# Unable to run chrome via eclipse and selenium

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Though i have added all the necessary JARs, there's still error on the "openqa.selenium" line and also the code doesn't run.

What must be the issue?

This is Java 14 and Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers.
selenium-java-3.141.59 and selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59

Please help me out here.

[image: Error Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the imports from main method
Remove the import you are getting error with.
Directly paste `WebDriver driver;` inside main method and hit ctrl+[spacebar] to import.
Clean the project.

It would be helpful if you could post the error msg that you get on hover to the import

Comment: "webdriver cannot be resolved to a type"

this is the error .

Comment: Hi, the issue is resolved , there was a issue with the versions and also the PATH was not added correctly, because after these above steps, i found errors.
Thanks for your time Sir.